# Use of -Wextra-semi-stmt?

Tags: c++, clang, compiler-warnings

The `-Wextra-semi-stmt` (included in `clang -Weverything`) complains about extra semicolons

```
static void f(void) {}
#define g(x) (void)x;

int main()
{
    f();; // warning
    g(0); // warning
}
```

I understand that the warning shows that there's one semicolon too many. But why am I warned? Is there any potential danger it tries to warn me of?

Comment: The warning is because it looks like a mistake.

Comment: There are certainly cases where the extra semicolon can cause a syntax error `if (cond) g(0); else g(1);`, but I wonder if there is an example where the extra semicolon results in code that is still valid but does something unintended.

Comment: Maybe it helps indirectly to catch code like `#define VALUE 17;` followed by `x=VALUE+3;` which sets `x` to be 17 instead of 20.

Comment: @NateEldredge It only warns for null statements, so that wouldn't trigger this warning. Instead there would be a warning about the unused expression result for `+3;` though: https://godbolt.org/z/ixxs3_

Comment: If you look at [the issue](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39111) and the [merge request](https://reviews.llvm.org/D52695?id=168000) introducing this particular warning to Clang, it doesn't seem to me that they had anything but style in mind (and they don't even seem sure whether the warning should be added).

Comment: @walnut: I chose a poor example.  Consider instead `#define foo(x) bar(x);`.  You will get a warning when you simply write `foo(3);`, which may help catch the mistake before you write `y = foo(3) + fum(7);` someday.

Comment: @NateEldredge Ah I see, I misunderstood your example then. It may be helpful prophylactically.